# A Basket has $5n$ balls, $4n$ are red and $n$ are green. $n$ is an integer greater than or equal to $1$

Tags: probability

If two balls are drawn out of the basket at random with replacement, what is the probability both are red? Without Replacement?

I understand how to do the probability portion i.e. $\frac{4n}{5n}\cdot \frac{4n}{5n} = \frac{16}{25}$ for the first question. Whatever number n is cancels out in the "with replacement" problem and the probability is always $\frac{16}{25}$.

However I am not sure how to handle the "without replacement" question. Should it be $\frac{4n}{5n}\cdot \frac{3n}{4n} = \frac35$? Im not sure how to handle removing a red ball. Shouldn't it be $\frac{4n}{5n}\cdot \frac{4n - 1}{5n - 1}$ since we are only removing $1$ red ball? This doesnt seem to line up with our classwork though...

Answer (score 1):

Picking 1 red will be $\frac{4n}{5n}$, after we remove 1 red, there are $4n-1$ red balls left out of $5n-1$, therefore drawing a second red ball will be $\frac{4n-1}{5n-1}$.

Therefore the probability of getting 2 red's without replacement is $\frac{4n}{5n} \cdot \frac{4n-1}{5n-1}$.

Comment: I was definitely over thinking it, this is 100% now the right answer now that I read it back.

Answer (score 0):

It is a simple case of conditional probability. The probability of getting a red ball for the first draw is $\frac{4n}{5n}=\frac{4}{5}$. The probability of drawing a red after, after a red ball was drawn on the first draw, is $\frac{4n-1}{5n-1}$. Note that not only the numerator is not $4n$, but the denominator is also not $5n$. This happens in dependent events.

Go through [this](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/ap-statistics/probability-ap/probability-multiplication-rule/a/general-multiplication-rule).

Consequently, the required probability is $$\frac{4}{5}\times\frac{4n-1}{5n-1}=\frac{16n-4}{25n-5}$$